# inner and left outer join combined - with two columns

Tags: sql, teradata

Just learning - thanks for the help.

**Table1: Breakfast**

| Animal | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Cow | Grass |
| Monkey | Banana |
| Monkey | Apples |
| Human | Cereal |
| Croc | Meat |

**Table 2: Lunch**

| Animal | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Cow | Grass |
| Monkey | Apples |
| Human | Sandwich |
| Croc | Meat |

How would you write a query to return All the animals but return NULL where the lunch is different to breakfast?

**Expected output:**

| Animal | Breakfast | Lunch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cow | Grass | Grass |
| Monkey | Banana | NULL |
| Monkey | Apples | Apples |
| Human | Cereal | NULL |
| Croc | Meat | Meat |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The problem is how you word the task. You don't want to show "all the *animals*", but all the *breakfasts*. So you select from the breakfast table. Then you want to join the lunch rows and still show the breakfast rows even if no matching lunch rows exists. That is an outer join. You want to outer join the lunch rows to the breakfast rows.

Comment: I see now that you have changed your request immensely. First it looked like there is a row for each animal in both tables, so a mere inner join and a case expression would have done. Then you added a row so that it was suddenly possible for an animal to appear multiple times in a table, which requires an outer join. Make sure such doesn't happen. Be clear on what you are after in your request. If you see from the answers that you asked the wrong question, accept the best answer and ask the new question in a new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the kind of sql that you are using:

If SQLite:

```
SELECT 
breakfast.animal AS animal, 
breakfast.food AS breakfast, 
CASE WHEN lunch.food=breakfast.food THEN lunch.food ELSE NULL END AS lunch 
FROM breakfast JOIN lunch ON breakfast.animal = lunch.animal;
```

else if MySQL:

```
SELECT 
breakfast.animal AS animal, 
breakfast.food AS breakfast, 
IF lunch.food=breakfast.food THEN lunch.food ELSE NULL END IF AS lunch 
FROM breakfast JOIN lunch ON breakfast.animal = lunch.animal;
```

There are other kinds of SQL, such as SQL Server, etc, so I'm just guessing that it might be either of those two.

Answer (score 1):

It's a plain Outer Join:

```
select
   b.animal,
  ,b.food as breakfast
  ,l.food as lunch
from breakfast b 
left join lunch l
  on b.animal = l.animal
 and a.food = b.food
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `full join`:

```
select coalesce(b.animal, l.animal) as animal,
       b.food as breakfast, l.food as lunch
from breakfast b full join
     lunch l
     on b.animal = l.animal
```

Comment: Thanks! - if there are two rows for a single animal and I wanted both breakfast rows to come back? is there a way to separate out into two rows? Updated output example

Comment: @djwaffles . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question, with sample data and desired results.  This answers the question that you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

it is simply a left join statement, remember that left join returns all indices in left table, the ones that are not paired are filled with 'null' value, the querty looks like

```
 select b.Animal, 
    b.Food as Breakfast, 
    l.Food as Lunch
from Breakfast as b
    left join Lunch as l
using(Food);
```

we are using the column Food from both table as index.
Take the index 'meat' then you have that croc eat meat as breakfast and for lunch so your output row is

```
| croc | meat | meat |
```

Now take the index 'cereal', we have that humans eat cereal for breakfast but humans don't have it for lunch then (as you choose left join) the value 'Null' is placed in the lunch column so we have

```
| human | cereal | null |
```

as output row.

Comment: You need to join on animal, too.

Comment: That was left join, i edited my answer already. I don't think you need to join both of them then,

Comment: dnoeth is right. Once you have many animals eating meat for lunch you'll get your croc/meat row multifold (once for each such animal) when not joining on animal, too,